# Mulesoft project that creates queues in Salesforce?

Tags: queue, salesforce, mule, mulesoft

I want to make an API with a POST request that receves a body with the queue name and the message to push to the queue, if that queue doesn't exist I want the API to create it in Salesforce and then publish the message to it.

I don't find any documentation for this only in Anypoint MQ "How to create a queue"